# Get a large amount of Test ETH on rinkeby

Tags: testnets, faucets

Is there an easy way to get a large amount of test ETH on rinkeby. Most of the faucets I found are either broken or send like max 0.1/24h. Yes I know I can test with smaller amounts and prices. Yes gas is cheap.
This is more so that I can get users to test the site and everything and not having to go to the faucets every single day just to get 0.1.
Is there such a way? Or the only wya is to incentivize people do help you with that?
from my understanding, rinkeby isn't mined either, so what are some good ways to accumulate?

Comment: Rinkeby is a PoA testnet if you want to test with a large number of user you can run your own test network.

Comment: @Ismael the problem is that services like Opensea are using rinkeby (other ones as well). If I run my own test network, not only do I need to spin up my own nodes and concensus algorithm, but also all of those services.

Comment: What type of test requires a large amount of ethers? Is opensea really needed? You could ask rinkeby admins, but from experience they won't change the actual faucet limits.